# -bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, bash, npm, env

I am trying to run this command `npm install -g bower` in my python virtual environment that I have my Django project enclosed in, and I end up getting the following error.

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

My npm file is located at the path above `/user/local/bin/npm`, what I am confused about is the bad interpreter bit, My os I am using is OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 if that matters. I have been stuck on this issue for hours combing stack overflow and blogs for the answer any suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `/usr/bin/env` binary? OS X might not allow that idiom for a shebang `#!` line. You can try replacing it with the actual path to whatever it is trying to run instead.

Comment: Okay it does have something to do with that, the issue is I'm just not sure what path to change it to exactly, this is what it is currently #!/usr/bin/env node.

Comment: What is the first line in `/usr/local/bin/npm`? It should be something like `/usr/bin/env command` and you just need to replace it with whatever the right path to `command` is.

Comment: Yeah, Just not sure what to set command to thats my issue right now.

Comment: You have the command *in the script*. To find out what the path is try `type command` in your shell.

Comment: type npm install -g bower and got this,                                                 npm is hashed (/usr/local/bin/npm)
install is /usr/bin/install
-bash: type: -g: not found, my command line skills are weak if you could not tell.
-bash: type: bower: not found

Comment: No... Look at the first line in the `npm` script. Find the argument being passed to `/usr/bin/env`. Run `type <that argument>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88627/discussion-between-appa-lover-and-etan-reisner).

Comment: Turns out I was missing /usr/bin/env/ on my computer so I had to factory reset it, even though your solution was a short term solution, for anyone who has this problem in the future this could possibly be the problem.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how that happened. I'm not sure that was the simplest solution to that problem but ok.

Comment: Ouch!  Factory *reset* to install `/usr/bin/env`?

Comment: Same issue on Raspberry Pi with Debian Jessie.